# what is the format of the value of date picker?

Tags: ms-access

In access, I use date picker to select a date, so what is the format of this date? is it a string or is it a date? If I want to compare this value with other date, what format I should use?

Comment: Short answer - it's a date.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a *date* value.

To compare dates, use *DateDiff*:

```
If DateDiff("d", Date, YourPickedDateValue) > 0 Then
    MsgBox "A future date cannot be used."
Else
    ' Do stuff.
End If
```

Comment: Note that you can also use standard arithmetic operators and comparison operators for dates, e.g. `If Date1 > Date2 Then` (note that all arithmetic operators are available, but not all are sensible)